# How can I configure grapeConfig.xml to use a private, remote repository?

Tags: maven, groovy, ivy, groovy-grape

I have a Maven repo set up as a website, hosted on an Amazon S3 bucket. In my Groovy code, if I use the @GrabResolver annotation with my @Grab annotation, Grape successfully finds the jar I need and the script runs.

I want to set up grapeConfig.xml so that I don't have to use @GrabResolver in my scripts, and I can't figure out how to do it. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape doesn't explain how to set a remote resolver that's not hosted on ibiblio. It does say to consult the Ivy documentation, but I can only find info in the Ivy docs on how to connect to an Ivy repo, rather than a Maven one (ie, one that has ivy.xml files).

In short: How can I configure my grapeConfig.xml so that I don't need a @GrabResolver annotation pointing to my remote repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I was massively overthinking it.

The solution is to just use an ibiblio tag anyway, specifying the Maven repo's root in the "root" attribute.

Comment: I wish you would have put down exactly how that line looks. I don't know what you mean by maven repo's root.

Comment: See an example here: [defaultGrapeConfig.xml](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/resources/groovy/grape/defaultGrapeConfig.xml)

Comment: See documentation reference [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-CustomizeIvysettings)